# Prevent layout from being pushed past certain border

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a LinearLayout with

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

inside a ConstraintLayout.
It looks the way its supposed to be if the screen height is larger than two times the screen width.
However, on devices that are wider, the top of my layout is pushed out of the screen.
However I want the top to stay visible and have the bottom part move out of the screen instead. Here is how I want the layout to act like:

1: Long enough device, everything fine:

> [image: long device]

2: Device that is a little wider, still everything fine:

> [image: screen with a 1:2 ratio]

3: Device that is even wider, the top of the layout should still be visible and the bottom should be pushed down:

> [image: even wider screen]

Comment: Seems like, instead of setting bottom constraint to the parent, you need to set the top constraint the parent:
`app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`so that the top will always be constrained to the parent's top and the bottom will push out of the window.

Comment: but I want the layout to be constrained to the parent's bottom if the parent's height is larger than the layout's

Comment: In that case, it seems like you would still need the top as constrained to the top, but also wrap the whole thing in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: You didn't attach your whole layout there, so it is a bit difficult to visualize. But when using dimension ratio, `height/width` - one should be `0dp`, like below.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
..
 >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/RED"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

Comment: Yes I know that, sorry for not making my problem very clear. Your Idea with the `ScrollView` did however lead me to the solution, I only had to put a `ConstraintLayout` into it and the content into the `ConstraintLayout` to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I did put it into a `ScrollView` but for `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` to also work, I needed to put the actual content into a `ConstraintLayout` in besaid `ScrollView`:

```
            <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutBgSnakes"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/imgView2"
                        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/..." />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/..." />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

**Note:** `android:fillViewport="true"` was the crucial line that made everything work.